# In WebRTC, I can establish a connection on my own computer, but I cannot connect over external networks

Tags: webrtc, svelte, stun, turn

https://github.com/chillyen/Funny-cat/blob/main/src/components/ChatInterface.svelte
In the ChatInterface.svelte file below, I have confirmed that my STUN and TURN servers can connect. However, in my tests, when I open Chrome and Edge on my computer and pair two users, they can connect to each other. I suspect that they might be using an internal network and not actually connecting through the TURN server. But when I try with a mobile phone and a computer, two different devices, they are unable to detect each other joining the same room server.
Connections can be established in different browsers or on different devices.

Comment: Have you configured Vite to accept connections from other devices using the [server.host](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options#server-host) option?

Comment: Yes, I have previously tried using server.host, but it displayed the error '[HMR][Svelte] Unrecoverable HMR error in <ChatInterface>: next update will trigger a full reload.' I haven't made any changes to the ChatInterface page. Currently, I've noticed that connections are more successful with Edge, whereas Chrome and Firefox seem to have more difficulty connecting successfully. If you'd like to try, I can email you a test account and password to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the STUN server you are using is not working. I checked your STUN server URI using the Trickle ICE web page, and I can't see any entry with type srflx.

Try this STUN server URI: "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302"

Or you can use any STUN server from this list: https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933

Before using any URI, use Trickle ICE to check whether it is working properly
Link: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/